# how to get variables of your API route with fetch method or similar

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a nodejs server whose routes I provide some variables. These should then be opened in .js scripts.

this is what a simplified route looks like for me:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index", { x: 123 });
});
```

Here "index" represents the html page that will be loaded.

I used the following fetch command:

```
fetch("/")
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.x);
   
  });
```

The result is an `undefined` and if I print only `data` then I get the whole html code back. But how can I get the supplied variable?

Comment: `res.render` produces an HTML page. The variables that went into producing it are not part of the response. But it also makes little sense to `fetch` an HTML page, because your Javascript code cannot do much with it. HTML pages are meant to be loaded by the browser directly, and rendered by the browser. What do you want to achieve with your Javascript code?

Comment: the variables can be data from a database which should then be mapped on the html page. Of course, there can also be IDs that I don't want to have anywhere on the HTML page.

Comment: If you want the HTML page displayed, you must navigate to it (through a hyperlink on another page, say), not `fetch` it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ejs as template engine, you can access those variable values from your html (ejs) file,
fine more here [using ejs in express](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application)